# Continuous Memory leak while using WpfHWndSource

Tags: wpf

I have to load an WPF User Control in an MFC Dialog that is being invoked from the ocx control. For this I have created a MFC Regular Dll(Mixed Mode Regular dll with clr option enabled), I have created a Dialog in this which hosts wpf user control using HWndSource. This exported dialog is placed as a child Dialog of thr above MFC dialog that is being invoked from the ocx. Ny intermediate dialog uses C++/Cli code.

When the main MFC dialog is closed, I am deleteing the ptr reference of the intermediate dialog created on the heap.But there after I still see a continous memory leak or growth.
In the destructor of the dialog, I am calling the delete on the HWndSource and the the wpf user control, so that its dispose should be called.

But I see a continuous leak there after.

Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: "I am calling the delete on the HWndSource and the the wpf user control, so that its dispose should be called". Huh? 1. HWndSource and WPF controls are managed objects, so there is no "delete" to call. 2. Dispose is completely optional (you can't leak memory by forgetting to call it). Please clarify what you actually did and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Could see some issues in google, with a continuous leak of 4kb when using HWndSource. My problem seems to be simialr to that.

[WPF Memory Leak on XP (CMilChannel, HWND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705849/wpf-memory-leak-on-xp-cmilchannel-hwnd)

I have simulated this issue in a sample MFC Dilaog Application which is in similar to my actual development application. In the applications's constructor, I have created a dummy HWndSource object first and it seems to show an improvement in the leakage of memory.

I have added another exported function in my clr enabled intermediate mfc regular dll which creates the HWndSource. I am calling this exported function from my application's constructor.

```
void CConnectionPanelExport::CreateHwndSource()
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)(gcnew  System::Windows::Interop::HwndSource(*gcnew  
      System::Windows::Interop::HwndSourceParameters("MyApplication")))->Handle.ToPointer();
    CWnd *temp= CWnd::FromHandle(hwnd);
    temp->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
}
```

From My Application's constructor, I Called

```
CConnectionPanelExport connectionPanelExport;
connectionPanelExport.CreateHwndSource();
```

This seems to keep the application's memory in control, but really I could not understand the probelm.

I have tried implementing this in my actual development application and I see application is getting closed when I am calling this exported method of /clr enabled dll. I am making a static linking of the clr enabled dll in a non clr enabled main application

Comment: You should use the Edit button under your question instead of posting an 'answer' to add information.