# How to count the number of memory leak in a C++ code?

Tags: visual-c++

```
int i=4;
int *p = new int(17);
i = *p;
delete p; 
p=0;
```

How to count how much memory is leaked? Is there like a unit to count this in?

Comment: What development platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect/avoid Memory leaks in your (Unmanaged) code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detect-avoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code)

Comment: And also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project

Comment: also, there is no memory leak in the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of variables involved, such as how 'new' or malloc actually work so it's hard to quantify with exact figures.  But since there's no garbage collection involved you can try a few things.  One thing I've done before is wrap the suspect code in a tight loop and watch the memory growth.